# Hierarchical data and GC

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, hierarchical

We have a hierarchical structure where each child node of the structure references the root node and the parent node, and also has a list of child nodes.

Something like this:

```
public class Node
{
     private readonly Node _root;
     private readonly Node _parent;
     private readonly IList<Node> _items;

     public Node(Node root, Node parent)
     {
         _root = root;
         _parent = parent;
         _items = new List<Node>();
     }

     public IList<Node> Items
     {
         get { return _items; }
     }
}
```

...and this:

```
class Tree
{
   // Root node is readonly
   readonly Node _root = new Node(null, null);

   public void ClearAndFill()
   {
      // Before creating a new tree, delete the existing child items
      _root.Items.Clear();

      var subNode1 = new Node(_root, _root);

      var subNode1_1 = new Node(_root, subNode1);
      subNode1.Items.Add(subNode1_1);

      var subNode2 = new Node(_root, _root);

      var subNode2_1 = new Node(_root, subNode2);
      subNode1.Items.Add(subNode2_1);

      _root.Items.Add(subNode1);
      _root.Items.Add(subNode2);
   }
}
```

My question is: If we call the ClearAndFill method several times, will there be a memory leak or will all nodes that are out of scope be collected by GC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Any objects which aren't referenced by any roots (global/static variables, any objects pointed by members of these variables, or temporary stack variables in all your threads at the moment the GC kicks in) will be collected.

.NET garbage collector is a [mark-and-sweep collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals), so the objects which are not accessible won't get marked and will therefore be collected.